# Pytorch implementation of MLP to solve XOR problem gives wrong prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to use an MLP to solve the XOR problem with pytorch.

```
from torch import nn

class XORLinear(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(XORLinear, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 1)
        self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        self.fc1.weight.data = torch.Tensor([[1, 1], [1, 1]])
        self.fc1.bias.data = torch.Tensor([[0, -1]])
        self.fc2.weight.data = torch.Tensor([[1, -2]])
        self.fc2.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, data):
        fc1 = self.fc1(data)
        activated = self.activation(fc1)
        fc2 = self.fc2(fc1)
        return fc2
```

I thought with the initial weights, the model should output correct predictions for all 4 possible inputs.

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = XORLinear().to(device)
x = torch.Tensor([[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]])
y_pred = model(x)
print(y_pred)
```

However, the predictions are

```
tensor([[0.],
        [2.],
        [1.],
        [1.]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

Why the result is like this?

Comment: What do you mean "*with the initial weights*"? Do you train your model or not?

Comment: @desertnaut As I'm not familiar with pytorch, I want to start with one known solution to see if I define the model correctly, e.g. syntax. I calculate the solution by hand and I think it should be correct. However, I don't know why the output is 2 for [0, 0]. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The results are correct for all inputs but (0,0), and I find the same result (2) as your network when doing the calculus with pen and paper. You must have got a parameter wrong in your calculations. I'd say your fc2.weight should be (1,-1) instead of (1,-2)